# Wildfly Swarm - Resource adapters (IBM wmq.jmsra.rar)

Tags: adapter, messaging, wildfly-swarm

In these moments, I'm trying to configure the IBM wmq.jmsra.rar resource adapter with Wildfly Swarm in a Java project but without success.
Those are the stepts that I've been doing till now:

1) pom.xml (the artifact was installed manually)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>mq</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.0.8</version>
    <type>rar</type>
</dependency>
```

2) module.xml for this resource adapter (in src/main/resources/modules/com/ibm/wsmq/main):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:2.0" name="com.ibm.mq">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="." />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.connector.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.headers.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jms.admin.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mqjms.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.jms.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.matchspace.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.provider.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.ref.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jar" />
        <resource-root path="dhbcore.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" />
        <module name="javax.resource.api" />
        <module name="javax.jms.api" />
        <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Note: In the main folder of this path I copied the mq-7.5.0.8.rar file too.

3) project-stages.yml:

resource-adapters:
   resource-adapters:
      mq:
         archive: mq.rar
         transaction-support: XATransaction
         connection-definitions:
            BSMConnectionFactoryHigh:
               class-name: com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl
               jndi-name: jms/bsmConnectionFactoryHigh
               config-properties:
                  hostName:
                     value: tqhr0712.sede.corp.sanpaoloimi.com
                  queueManager:
                     value: TQHR0712
                  port:
                     value: 1412
                  channel:
                     value: CH.BSMA.CONN
                  transportType:
                     value: CLIENT
         admin-objects:
            BSMSendQueueHigh:
               class-name: com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy
               jndi-name: jms/bsmSendQueueHigh
               config-properties:
                  baseQueueName:
                     value: QLOCAL.DATAGRAM.WUO.UOS4APPO9
                  baseQueueManagerName:
                    value: TQHR0712

deployment: 
   com.ibm.mq:mq.rar:

Then, when I run the project I get this error:

```
2018-02-08 10:33:54 INFO <org.jboss.as.server.deployment> <MSC service thread 1-7> WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment mq.rar (runtime-name: mq.rar) in 72ms
2018-02-08 10:33:54 INFO <org.jboss.as.controller> <main> WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.resourceadapters-subsystem (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."mq.rar".CONFIGURE_MODULE]
```

Someone would be kind to help to fix this problem?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Hi again. Step by step I'm configure Wildfy Swamr and ibm wm resource adapter. Now, after start up the java project, I get errors like this one: Code: Class: com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl Property: CCSID Type: int

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to tell you that I found how to make the Wildfly Swarm and IBM websphere mq resource adapter integration with success.

These are the steps to follow:

**1) Get the wmq.jmsra.rar from IBM (version 8.x)**

**2) Creating the artifacts for this file like this:**

```
                   <dependency>
                                   <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>mq</artifactId>
                                   <version>8.0.0.7</version>
                                   <type>rar</type>
                   </dependency> 
                   <dependency>
                                   <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>mq</artifactId>
                                   <version>8.0.0.7</version>
                                   <type>jar</type>
                                   <scope>provided</scope>
                   </dependency>
```

**3) src/main/resources:**
    a) Create the folder modules.
    b) Inside modules folder create com/ibm/mq/main.
   c) Inside the main folder copy the resource adapter (the .rar file) and 
      rename it as mq.rar.
   d) Inside main folder create the file module.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:2.0" name="com.ibm.mq">    
    <resources>    
        <resource-root path="." />    
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.connector.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.headers.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jar" />
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar" />    
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar" />    
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.jar" />    
        <resource-root path="com.ibm.mqjms.jar" />    
    </resources>    
    <dependencies>    
        <module name="javax.api" />    
        <module name="javax.resource.api" />    
        <module name="javax.jms.api" />    
        <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api" />    
    </dependencies>    
</module>
```

**4) project-stages.yml:**

swarm:
    jca:
       archive-validation:
          enabled: false
          fail-on-warn: false

resource-adapters:
   resource-adapters:
      mq:
         archive: mq.rar
         transaction-support: XATransaction
         connection-definitions:
            ReinoltroConnectionFactory:
               class-name: com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl
               jndi-name: jms/testConnectionFactory
               recovery-username: 
               recovery-password: 
               tracking: false
               pool-name: MQCONNF
               config-properties:
                  hostName:
                     value: 
                  queueManager:
                     value: 
                  port:
                     value: 
                  channel:
                     value: 
                  transportType:
                     value: CLIENT
         admin-objects:
            testQueue:
               class-name: com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy
               jndi-name: jms/testQueue
               pool-name: MQQUEUENAME
               config-properties:
                  baseQueueName:
                     value: 
                  baseQueueManagerName:
                    value:

deployment: 
   com.ibm:mq.rar:

**5) Java code (send message using JMS 2)**

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class RichiesteServiceImpl {
 ....
    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/reinoltroConnectionFactory")
    JMSContext jmsContext;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/reinoltroBDQueue")    
    Queue testQueue;
 .....

     public boolean sendMessage()  {

        boolean esitoReinoltro = false;

        try {
            jmsContext.createProducer().send(reinoltroQueue, "Messaggio di prova" );

            esitoReinoltro = true;

            return esitoReinoltro;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {        
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and the job is done.

Comment: Hi Ernesto - Can you help with your thoughts on  a RuntimeException which I'm facing after following the exact config steps followed above  [using wmq.jmsra v9.0.4.0] :
org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.resourceadapters-subsystem"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"mq.rar\".CONFIGURE_MODULE is missing [jboss.resourceadapters-subsystem]"]}